# uber dependency compiling error - Android

Tags: uber-api

On adding this line of code to build.gradle

```
compile 'com.uber.sdk:rides-android:0.5.3'
```

It shows an error when the project is building

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies'. > Dependency Error. See console for details.
```

the error log from gradle console

> Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
>   WARNING: WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
>            In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
>   WARNING: WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
>            In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
>   WARNING: WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
>            In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
>   WARNING: WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
>            In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
>   Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
>   WARNING: Conflict with dependency 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305'. Resolved versions for app (1.3.9) and test app (2.0.1) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.
>   :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:checkDebugManifest
>   :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2500Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72500Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2500Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2500Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2500Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2500Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2500Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42500Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2500Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComUberSdkCoreAndroid053Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComUberSdkRidesAndroid053Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareDebugDependencies
>   :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestEspressoEspressoCore222Library
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestEspressoEspressoIdlingResource222Library
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestExposedInstrumentationApiPublish05Library
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestRules05Library
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestRunner05Library
>   :app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
>   Conflict with dependency 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305'. Resolved versions for app (1.3.9) and test app (2.0.1) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.

FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies'.

  > Dependency Error. See console for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Please help

Comment: Show those detail which your error message says about. Maybe you did not  inluded everything in your gradle file ?

Comment: @Rafal i have updated it in the question above

Comment: Which version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: The latest version  2.2.2

Comment: @Yan Chummar This sounds like a problem: :app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies Conflict with dependency 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305'. Resolved versions for app (1.3.9) and test app (2.0.1) differ. Show also your dependencies list. Maybe you have findbug included in your other dependencies and this causing the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed by force the com.google.findbugs to use a lower version